# Aligning words in 2 sentences using a numpy 2d array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given 2 sentences, I need to align the words in those sentences based on the best similarity match between the words in these sentences.

For instance, consider 2 sentences:

```
sent1 = "John saw Mary" # 3 tokens
sent2 = "All the are grown by farmers" # 6 tokens
```

Here, for each token in `sent1`, I need to find the most similar token in `sent2`. Further, if a token in `sent2` is already matched with a token in `sent1`, then it cannot be matched with another token in `sent1`.

For the purpose, I use a similarity matrix between the tokens in a sentence, as given below

```
cosMat = (array([[0.1656948 , 0.16653526, 0.13380264, 0.09286133, 0.16262592,
         0.14392284],
        [0.40876892, 0.46331584, 0.28574535, 0.34924293, 0.2480594 ,
         0.25846344],
        [0.15394737, 0.10269377, 0.12189645, 0.09426117, 0.09631223,
         0.10549664]], dtype=float32)
```

`cosMat` is a `2d ndarray of size (3,6)` which contain the cosine similarity scores of the tokens in both the sentences.

`np.argmax` would provide the following array as output

```
np.argmax(cosMat,axis=1)
 array([1, 1, 0]))
```

However this is not a valid solution, as the first and second tokens of `sent1` aligns with second token of `sent2`.

Instead I chose to do the following:

```
sortArr = np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(-cosMat.ravel()), cosMat.shape))

rowSet = set()
colSet = set()
matches = list()
for item in sortArr[0]:
    if item[1] not in colSet:
        if item[0] not in rowSet:
            matches.append((item[0],item[1],cosMat[item[0],item[1]]))
            colSet.add(item[1])
            rowSet.add(item[0])
matches
```

This gives the following output, which is the desirable output:

```
[(1, 1, 0.46331584), (0, 0, 0.1656948), (2, 2, 0.121896446)]
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to achieve, for what I have done using the code above?

Comment: So here the answer is `saw --> the`, `John --> All` and `Mary --> are`?

Comment: @swag2198 - Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, it requires you to copy the initial similarity matrix. Everytime you find the best match, you discard the two tokens from the pair by replacing the correspond row and column in the copied matrix by `0`. This ensures you do not find the same token in multiple pairs.

```
res = []
mat = np.copy(cosMat)
for _ in range(mat.shape[0]):
    i, j = np.unravel_index(mat.argmax(), mat.shape)
    res.append((i, j, mat[i, j]))
    mat[i,:], mat[:,j] = 0, 0
```

Will return:

```
[(1, 1, 0.46331584), (0, 0, 0.1656948), (2, 2, 0.12189645)]
```

However, considering you only using `np.argsort` once. Yours will, most probably, be faster.

---

Otherwise, I would rewrite your version, for conciseness, as:

```
sortArr = zip(*np.unravel_index(np.argsort(-cosMat.ravel()), cosMat.shape))

matches = []
rows, cols = set(), set()
for x, y in sortArr:
    if x not in cols and y not in rows:
        matches.append((x, y, cosMat[x, y]))
        cols.add(x)
        rows.add(y)
```

---

You could use a single set instead of two, by using some kind of prefix for the indices in order to distinguish rows from columns. Here again I'm not sure there's much gain in doing so:

```
matches = []
matched = set()
for x, y in sortArr:
    if 'i%i'%x not in matched and 'j%i'%y not in matched:
        matches.append((x, y, cosMat[x, y]))
        matched.update(['i%s'%x, 'j%s'%y])
```